# Summarize credit card transactions

Tags: excel

I export my credit card details as csv and then used text to columns to get them to table in readable format like this.

[image]

How could I query / sort out how much I have spend in specific stores combined (so if the merchant is the same, just add amount value) during the years so it would look something like this

[image]

EDIT: added data as text. NOTE! only K-market Haikko is as merchant twice in the example data

```
  Date (YYYY-MM-DD as UTC),Merchant,Txn Amount (Funding Card),Txn Currency (Funding Card),Txn Amount (Foreign Spend),Txn Currency (Foreign Spend),Card Name,Card Last 4 Digits,Type,Category,Notes
2023-01-29,T:mi Fahri Lati,-24.00,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-29,K-citymarket Porvoo,-94.06,EUR,,,Visa Credit,000,,Groceries,
2023-01-29,Subway,-7.10,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-28,K-market Haikko,-9.08,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-28,Sadama Turg,-24.26,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-28,Bolt.eu/o/2301281350,-5.20,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Travel,
2023-01-28,Sports Direct,-9.00,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Shopping,
2023-01-28,R-kiosk Ulemiste Kesku,-1.55,EUR,,,Mastercard Credit,0000,,Shopping,
2023-01-28,House Ulemiste Keskus,-21.23,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Shopping,
2023-01-28,Bolt.eu,-5.00,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Travel,
2023-01-28,"Viking Line, Viking Xp",-57.20,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Travel,
2023-01-28,K-market Haikko,-6.00,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-27,Vikingline.fi,-356.40,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Travel,
2023-01-27,S-market Nasi,-19.52,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-26,Foodora Finland,-15.50,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-25,Aliexpress,-5.86,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Shopping,
2023-01-25,K-market Haikko,-15.92,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-25,Lounasravintola,-11.00,EUR,,,Mastercard Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-24,K-rauta.fi,-107.60,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-23,Sale Gammelbacka,-16.47,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-23,Motonet Porvoo,-16.98,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Shopping,
2023-01-22,Cmore.fi,-19.95,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Bills,
2023-01-22,Easypark Oy,-1.09,EUR,,,Mastercard Credit,0000,,Travel,
2023-01-21,Restaurant Roka,-26.00,EUR,,,Mastercard Credit,0000,,Eating Out,
2023-01-21,Sale Gammelbacka,-8.43,EUR,,,Mastercard Credit,0000,,Groceries,
2023-01-21,St1 Porvoo Eestinmaki,-77.08,EUR,,,Visa Credit,0000,,Travel,
```

Comment: A pivot table perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried sumifs() ? I would have a go but you have not given data but an image.

Comment: Please paste your data as text, this can allow people to quickly copy and paste to try things for you

Comment: Now data is added as text @WhatsThePoint

Comment: Please paste your data as text with a separator like ";"

Comment: Changed to original csv which I get when exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column M is the Unique function to make a unique list of Merachands.
Column N a Sumifs function, to calculate.

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B27)
=-SUMIFS($C$2:$C$27;$B$2:$B$27;M3)
```

The minus symbol turns everyting into plus values

But the best way is probably a Pivot Table. Very easy to change also.
For that your data must be in a table, then just go to Insert-->Pivot Table

[image]

Also Advanced Filter (Special Filter) would be possbile, but more work.